# A table still exists when dropped

Tags: sql, oracle

When I used this command it worked, which means my table was dropped

```
DROP TABLE <TABLE NAME> ;
```

But when I query

```
SQL>SELECT * FROM TAB;
```

My dropped tables are not showing. But some other tables like `BIN$+NP+VhP7RF2hLc1AoJf+gg==$0` are.

How do I drop this type of table?

Comment: Incidentally, [TAB is deprecated](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/statviews_5178.htm#REFRN29068), you should use [USER_TABLES](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/statviews_5480.htm#REFRN26286) instead...

Comment: If you have doubts about the results of running a command, the most effective response may be to read the documentation for the command: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9003.htm

Answer (score 6):

You're using a recent version of Oracle and your table has been placed in the [RECYCLEBIN](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/tables011.htm#ADMIN11679). To get rid of it completely in the first instance you can use

```
drop table <table_name> purge;
```

To quote from [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_9003.htm#SQLRF01806) on DROP TABLE:

> Specify PURGE if you want to drop the table and release the space
>   associated with it in a single step. If you specify PURGE, then the
>   database does not place the table and its dependent objects into the
>   recycle bin.
>   ...
>   Using this clause is equivalent to first dropping
>   the table and then purging it from the recycle bin. This clause lets
>   you save one step in the process. It also provides enhanced security
>   if you want to prevent sensitive material from appearing in the
>   recycle bin.

The RECYCLEBIN can come in handy though... it's a additional back-up for when you've just accidentally dropped the wrong table. If you specify PURGE when dropping a table you'll never be able to retrieve the table from the RECYCLEBIN. Note, however, that if you DROP *without* purging the space used by the object will not be freed.

To remove the table from the RECYCLEBIN you would use:

```
purge table "BIN$+NP+VhP7RF2hLc1AoJf+gg==$0";
```

Note that as the object name is cased you need the double quotes.

Comment: @user2397125: ORA-00942 is "table or view does not exist".  This indicates that either A) the table was entered incorrectly, B) that table name wasn't enclosed in double-quotes, or C) it's already been purged from the recycle bin.  I can't see your database so that's about all I can tell you.

Comment: @Ben: snuck the OP in under the wire.  :-)  Thanks.

Comment: @bibhudash, that error is pretty self-explanatory. The object you're trying to purge does not exist.

Comment: @Ben Is there any solution to drop the following tables-:

Comment: BIN$+NP+VhP7RF2hLc1AoJf+gg==$0

Comment: BIN$cps2+IZtTJ2lon//II+Z9w==$0

Comment: BIN$fcE4FR0URp6MUBmiVyMgSg==$0

Comment: This is very irritating @ Ben. Whenever I use the command SELECT * FROM TAB; Those tables are coming. Now I am using PURGE when I want to DROP a table and that is working good and no other tables are coming. But I want to drop those please help.

Comment: @bibhudas the command, as outlined in the documentation is `purge table "BIN$+NP+VhP7RF2hLc1AoJf+gg==$0";`, as the table name is cased you _must_ enclose it in double quotes, `"`.

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens in SSMS. The reason behind this is, you must have open that dropped table(Design) in another window.

This was my case, cache/bin still preserve the reference until previous design window is closed.