# release the physical space occupied by oracle tablespace after deleting back up table

Tags: oracle11g, tablespace

I am new on oracle and i am working to remove space occupied tablespace on oracle database.

So i am facing this issue:

There are so many back up tables are created on oracle tablespace. 
I have removed the all that backed up and temp table from that tablespace
But there is not space reduced occupied by tablespace after  doing this.

Comment: Have you deleted the data from the tables, or truncated them?

Comment: If you've dropped then a duplicate is [A table still exists when dropped](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16626006/458741); if you've deleted; if you've deleted then the duplicate is on DBA.SE http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/10514/5743

Comment: i have dropped the temp and backed up tables from the tablespace. is there no chance to get space if i deleted  huge rows from table?

Comment: space will not get released by deleting rows, you should proceed with "row movement enable" or go through with offload process if you wish to release the space in OS immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option1-Offloading Process**

Backup tablespace=>drop tablespace=>restore same tablespace can help you to resolve the issue:

```
expdp user/password directory=name_of_directory dumpfile=tablespace_dumpfile.dmp logfile=tablespace_dumpfile.log  tablespaces=tablespace_name;

drop tablespace tablespace_name including contents and datafiles;

impdp user/password directory=name_of_directory dumpfile=tablespace_dumpfile.dmp logfile=tablespace_dumpfile_import.log  tablespaces=tablespace_name;
```

**Option2-Row moment Enable:**

```
alter table mytable enable row movement;
alter table mytable shrink space;
```

Next, check the total size occupied by objects:

```
select sum(bytes) from dba_segments where tablespace_name='tablespace_name';
```

Now, try to resize datafile to release space:

```
alter database datafile 'datafile_location_file_name' resize <<< size from above select statement >>>;
```